# git fetch on a brand new local repository

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I am a little bit confused with git. I used the followed commands in that order

```sh
git init
git fetch https://git.xyz.com/myrepo/app.git
```

At this point, there are no branches, no files on the local computer. So, my question is. What's the point of the fetch after init? At this point how can I download the files? I used

```sh
git remote add origin https://git.xyz.com/myrepo/app.git
git merge
fatal: No remote for the current branch.
```

I couldn't create a branch with

```sh
git checkout master
```

Finally, I used

```sh
git pull
```

to download the actual files. I was trying to fetch and merge instead of pull directly according to the manual. So where am I wrong here? Why Fetch/Merge didn't work? The `clone` alternative works but I would like to try the Fetch/Merge.

Comment: Were you able to clone the remote branch?

Comment: @Simon yes. If I use `git clone https://git.xyz.com/myrepo/app.git` it works as expected

Comment: i'm confused. did it solve your problem?

Comment: @Simon I didn't use the clone at all. I just followed the steps in my question. The `git pull` actually did the job, but why fetch/merge didn't work?

Comment: You said there are no files on the local computer. Are you only seeing an empty folder?

Comment: @Simon Before I run `git pull` yes there were no files on the local computer. After I run `git pull` git downloaded all the files. I would like to try the fetch/merge alternative instead of a `clone`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you start with an empty directory, so that:

> ```
> git init
> ```

creates a new, empty repository, your *second* step:

> ```
> git fetch https://git.xyz.com/myrepo/app.git
> ```

has now done the main bulk of the work of a `git clone` command.  You have, however, omitted two key steps.  The first one should be done *before* running `git fetch`, though you can just re-run `git fetch` afterward:

- `git remote add`, which would give you a *name* for the URL `https://git.xyz.com/myrepo/app.git`.  This step is not technically necessary: if you are a Git expert, you can do everything you need to do without this name.  But if you're *not* a Git expert, you're setting yourself up for some big headaches.

  To fix this part, you would need to run:

  ```
  git remote add origin https://git.xyz.com/myrepo/app.git
  ```

  then run:

  ```
  git fetch origin
  ```
- The last step you're missing is `git checkout`.

  Because you omitted the `git remote add` step, actually doing the checkout now is tricky.

Here's what you  actually did:

> ```
> git remote add origin https://git.xyz.com/myrepo/app.git
> ```

This is good: it's exactly what you needed to run.

> ```
> git merge
> ```

This failed, as you saw, in part because you have not yet repeated the `git fetch` step, but more importantly, because you have not run `git checkout` yet.

> ```
> git pull
> ```

This runs `git fetch`, followed by a second Git command.  So that handled the missing `git fetch` step.

The interesting thing is that, after this `git fetch` step, `git pull`'s *second* Git command is *normally* `git merge`.<sup>1</sup>  That still would have failed—but `git pull` has a special case built into it.  It notices when the initial `git checkout` has never been used, and instead of running the normal second command, it runs `git checkout` for you!

So, in the end (and with a little bit of extra pain), you had Git run all the correct commands.  For future reference, though, note that:

```
git clone https://git.xyz.com/myrepo/app.git new-clone
```

is generally a lot easier to use.  This runs *six* commands for you, five of them being Git commands:

1. `mkdir`, to create a new empty directory (and then an internal `cd` or `chdir` to enter it to run the remaining 5 Git commands);
2. `git init`, to create a new empty repository *in* the new directory;
3. `git remote add`, to set up the *remote* that Git will use later to make things easier for you;
4. any extra `git config` steps you specify on the command line (if you don't specify any, none are actually used here, but it's useful to know *when* they'd be run, if you had listed them);
5. `git fetch`; and
6. `git checkout`.

Note that the *name* of the directory created in step 1 is the argument after the URL.  If you don't give such an argument, `git clone` will figure out a directory name based on the URL you are using with `git clone`.  The URL you give is used in step 3, in the `git remote add`.  The name of the remote, in steps 3 and 5, is `origin`.<sup>2</sup>  The name of the *branch* to create in step 6 is supplied by the Git at the URL you give.<sup>3</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>You can change this with either configuration information or command-line flags.

<sup>2</sup>You can change this with the `-o` option, or, in an upcoming Git version, with configuration information.

<sup>3</sup>You can change this with the `-b` option.  Note that when it is a *branch* name, as is the usual case, this really does *create* the branch in your own repository:

- The `fetch` step (step 5) copies all the *commits* from the source Git, but does not copy any of the *branch names*.  Instead, it creates *remote-tracking names* from each of their branch names.  Once you have your own Git repository, it is up to you to create whatever branch names you want: the `-b` option lets you choose one instead of taking the other Git's recommendation, or, if you like, you can use the `-n` option to stop `git clone` from doing step 6 entirely.
- The `checkout` step uses `git checkout`'s "DWIM mode" to create the branch (although `git clone` gets to cheat a little bit, and internally, does actually cheat—this relies on the fact that the fetch *code* is built into the same binary as `git clone`).

The process of creating a new branch via "DWIM mode" is a little bit complicated and relies on those remote-tracking names.  This is meant to make using Git easier, and for a standard `git clone`, it actually succeeds in this goal, but it's definitely convoluted.   It is also why you need to be a Git expert if you don't use `git remote add`: you don't get the remote-tracking names if you don't have a remote!